# Pandas - Assign value to row if matching condition and a time range defined in other column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a question that seems to be simple but I haven't been able to find an answer on this platform. I have done gps-tracking experiments with multiple devices on different days.

I now have two dataframes. The first dataframe contains gps points with a gpsnumber, timestamp, longitude & latitude. The second dataframe contains information about the experiments which we wrote down ourselves when handing out and in the gpstrackers. There are columns for the experiment number, the gps-number used, the hand_out_time and the hand_in_time.

I have two goals: 
(1) I want to match gps data to the right experiment and
(2) I want to delete all the rows that are not within the experiment times.

This looks like:

```
df:
    GPS_number  date_time           lon         lat     
744 16          2019-12-12 10:58:41 4.913158    52.367210   
745 16          2019-12-12 11:10:05 4.913158    52.367210   
746 16          2019-12-12 11:10:56 4.913085    52.367130   
747 16          2019-12-12 11:29:31 4.913085    52.367130   
748 16          2019-12-12 11:29:36 4.913191    52.367092
```

```
df2:
    Measurement GPS_number  Visitor_type    Hand_out_time       Hand_in_time
0   1           3           Tourist         2019-12-12 11:35:00 2019-12-12 12:16:00
1   2           3           Tourist         2019-12-12 12:47:00 2019-12-12 14:34:00
2   3           5           Member          2019-12-12 11:10:00 2019-12-12 13:36:00
3   4           6           Member          2019-12-12 11:27:00 2019-12-12 12:55:00
4   5           6           Tourist         2019-12-12 12:54:00 2019-12-12 15:22:00
```

I tried to use masks, but that does not work since I guess it can not match the hand out time and the hand in time correctly..

```
mask = (df['GPS_number'] = (df2['GPS_number'] & (df['date_time'] > df2['Hand_out_time'] & (df['date_time'] < df2['Hand_in_time)
df = df[mask]
```

Would be great if someone could show me how to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along these lines might work, more of an idea than a promise of fully functioning code for your df.

```
df = df.merge(
    df[['Measurement','GPS_number','Visitor_type','Hand_out_time','Hand_in_time']],
    left_on = 'GPS_number',
    right_on = 'GPS_number',
    how = 'left'
    )

mask = ((df['date_time'] > df['Hand_out_time']) & (df['date_time']<df['Hand_in_time']))
df = df[mask]
```

I don't believe mask works across multiple df in the way you originally had it. What you're trying to do looks to me like the Python equivalent of a SQL left join with multiple on conditions. The thought here is to merge with a simple match, which will make a very unwieldy dataset with multiple duplicate entries. Applying the mask to that redefined df will then be a bit like adding in the extra on conditions, and will hopefully give you what you want.

The other potential error could be if you have inconsistent dtypes between the columns.

If above doesn't do the job, comment with the error message or incorrect result and I'll try edit accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your response, unfortunately it does not work yet. The merge is going well, but the mask is not succesful. I got this error message.

 File "<ipython-input-42-90257f5aa350>", line 8
    mask = ((df['date_time'] > df['Hand_out_time']) & (df['date_time']<df['Hand_in_time))
                                                                                         ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: @Ellard the mask was missing a closing quote in the code I posted. Try mask = ((df['date_time'] > df['Hand_out_time']) & (df['date_time']<df['Hand_in_time'])) or see the edited response. EOL string literal will often indicated a missing or misplaced quotation mark

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, unfortunately that change did not really make a difference. This is the error I still get:
File "<ipython-input-32-df4da48b6d59>", line 1
    mask = ((df['date_time'] > df['Hand_out_time']) & (df['date_time']<df['Hand_in_time))
                                                                                         ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

I am now consideringusing append, maybe that will help me.

Comment: @Ellard it looks like you didn't quite copy and paste in the new text. The error message you posted is still missing a closing single quote and a closing bracket. You pasted"df['Hand_in_time", which would give you the error. That answer is missing the '] that should appear when using the bracket notation to reference a dataframe column.

Comment: I guess your right! Thanks, I don't get any error anymore and as far as I can check the dataframe, it seems like it works! Thanks a lot.